# C# 4.0 and .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

So we've finally got VS2010 on some developer stations at work and can use the C# 4.0 features.  Although most of what we develop will still have to target .Net 3.5 for the time being.

When I start a new project and set the target to .Net 3.5, it still allows me to use C# 4.0 such as dynamic.  Can you therefore use C#4.0 features whilst targetting .net 3.5 and will these features work in environments where .Net 4.0 is not available?

Thanks.

Comment: Ya, this is weird. I noticed that on our app as well and ours is 2.0. I'd be interested in what the answers would be.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`dynamic` code will not compile if you target the .NET 3.5 framework.

To be more clear, the compiler will allow you to *define* and *assign* a `dynamic` variable, such as:

```
dynamic x = 3;
```

That one line of code will compile, because `dynamic` just compiles to `object` as far as types are concerned.  But if you then try to *do* anything with that variable, as in:

```
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

... then the compiler would have to generate code to discover/coerce the real type, which it cannot do; you'll get the following compile errors:

> 1. Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported
> 2. One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

The C# 4 compiler relies on the DLR and specifically the Microsoft.CSharp assembly for everything related to `dynamic`.  These aren't available in .NET 3.5.  So the answer is no, you cannot use `dynamic` when targeting Framework version 3.5.

Comment: I often wondered what the difference was. Thank you Aaronaught

Comment: Reading that error makes me wonder, so what happens if you included the those 2 dlls as copy local, would that be enough? Or would it never find those dlls for picking the GAC version of the older framework always?

Comment: @Chris: Microsoft.CSharp doesn't actually *contain* the DLR; the DLR is part of the framework itself. So no, including that DLL won't help you; even if you do get it to compile, it won't actually run.

Comment: +1 Another solution if you googled the 2 error messages that Aaronaught lists, is to just add a Reference to Microsoft.CSharp 4.0

Comment: Jeremy - you can't reference Microsoft.CSharp 4.0 from .NET 3.5 I don't think?